# Django dynamic file output on form submit doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, django, firefox, mobile

I'm trying to output a file by writing to io.BytesIO and send it when form is submitted as file attachment. Everything works fine in Firefox on Linux, but mobile browsers send a GET request when download is accepted in browser and save the HTTP response as the downloaded file.

Here is my view function:

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import FileResponse, HttpResponse
import io


@csrf_exempt
def download_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        buffer.write('Text file content'.encode('UTF-8'))
        buffer.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='file.txt')
    return HttpResponse('<form method="post"><button>Download</button></form>')
```

This is what the logs look like when form is submitted from Firefox on Linux:

```
[20/Sep/2020 18:15:31] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17
```

Downloaded file on Linux:

```
Text file content
```

This is what the logs look like when form is submitted from Firefox on Android:

```
[20/Sep/2020 18:16:47] "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 17
[20/Sep/2020 18:16:48] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52
```

Downloaded file on Android:

```
<form method="post"><button>Download</button></form>
```

I am using Python 3.8.5 and Django 3.1.1.

Comment: INFO: it seems this is something with the firefox android, In chrome android the download seems fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue

In the Firefox android app, the app is sending an HTTP GET request after ***confirming the Download*** action. You can see the server logs of the same (in OP too,)

[image: OP behaviour]

#### What is the solution?

It is *not recommended* to use an HTTP POST method to download a file, use HTTP GET  instead ( Ref: [Which HTTP method to use for file downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355175/which-http-method-to-use-for-file-downloading) ). So, change your view accordingly to download the file.

```
def sample_view(request):
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    buffer.write('Text file content'.encode('UTF-8'))
    buffer.seek(0)
    return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename='file.txt')
```

[image: HTTP get download]

Comment: Thanks, looks like Firefox android app is the problem here. One problem is that the actual view function does some database changes before returning the file, so I thought the POST method was appropriate. I have solved this by first doing database changes and then redirecting to download file view.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Consider using HttpResponse or StreamingHttpResponse with proper content type and content disposition.

### Example

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
import io

@csrf_exempt
def download_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        buffer.write('Text file content'.encode('UTF-8'))
        buffer.seek(0)
        response = HttpResponse(buffer, content_type='text/plain')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.txt'

        return response

    return HttpResponse('<form method="post"><button>Download</button></form>')
```

## References

StreamingHttpResponse: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse

Comment: [From the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects), *"FileResponse is a subclass of StreamingHttpResponse optimized for binary files. It uses wsgi.file_wrapper if provided by the wsgi server, otherwise it streams the file out in small chunks."*

Comment: I didn't try your answer, but, what advantage will someone get if they use your solution over `FileResponse`, which is already done in OP?

Comment: UPDATE: When I tried with Firefox Android to download the file, the content was not the *"Text file content"*